# Pool not using full capacity of processors

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm using Python3's `multiprocessing` lib so that I can execute my code on my university cluster. Though I noticed that a `Pool` does not distribute the work in the best way possible and I'm looking for a way to avoid this. For instance in this code:

```
>>> from time import sleep
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> 
>>> def f(i):
...     if i == 0:
...             sleep(4)
...     print(i, end='\t')
... 
>>> with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
...     _ = pool.map(f, range(100))
... 
13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  0   1   2   34  5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
```

we can see that the first task to proceed takes a humongous amount of time compared to the 99 others, still one `Process` is in charge of the 12 first tasks. This means that Process #2 shall execute tasks 13 -> 99, and then wait for Process #1 to finish (therefore processing 1 -> 12). This is clearly not optimal since Process #1 finishes way before Process #2 finishes task 1.

Is there a way to force Process #1 to keep executing tasks as long as some are available, i.e. in this case forcing tasks 2 -> 12 to be executed on Process #2 ?

I tried tweaking the `chunksize` argument, helping a bit (e.g. setting it to 2 forces process #1 to execute tasks 3 -> 12), yet this is still not optimal.